# How to retrieve files from an MS Access "Attachment" field via JDBC?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, blob

I wrote a small Java application to read data from an Access 2007 database. I can read all fields but not the one containing the photo. The field type is "Attachment".

When I call the `.getBlob()` method of the `ResultSet` object I catch an "UnsupportedOperationException".

As suggested on several websites I tried to call `.getBytes()` and `.getBinaryStream()` methods but both only return the filename of the attachment but not it's content.

Comment: The attachment datatype contains a recordset that can be read with ADO or DAO. There are notes here that may give you some clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223266/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-an-attached-file-from-an-ms-access-db-into-a-vba-var/14235764#14235764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver can extract files from an Attachment field in an Access database. For a table named [AttachmentsTable]

**ID** - AutoNumber, Primary Key
**Description** - Text(255)
**Attachments** - Attachment

The following code will extract all of the files in the [Attachments] field for the record where ID=1:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;
import net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment;

...

String dbFileSpec = "C:/Users/Public/AttachmentsDB.accdb";
String connStr = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFileSpec;
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr)) {
    try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(
                "SELECT Attachments FROM AttachmentsTable WHERE ID=1")) {
            rs.next();
            // retrieve array of net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment objects
            Attachment[] atts = (Attachment[]) rs.getObject(1);
            for (Attachment att : atts) {
                System.out.println(att.getName());
                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(
                        new File("C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/" + att.getName()), 
                        att.getData());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on using the UCanAccess JDBC driver see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Answer (score 0):

[HXTT Access](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html) can get uncompressed Attachment data, but doesn't support compressed Attachment data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty workaround for certain situations...

The XML export of a table contains the pictures base64 encoded with some extra data. A java application using stax XML API can handle this data easily. It's almost straight forward but a 20 byte overhead in the beginning of the binary data has to be truncated. [Read this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163862/xml-export-from-access-2007-base64-attachments)

If you are in the compfortable situation to do it only ones you are finished. If you have to do this on a regular basis but not in real time you can try the .ExportXML API from access described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692914.aspx).

cheers